# Azure SQL Delay

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure app service with pricing tier S1 and Azure SQL DB of pricing tier S1 for an iOS application with https. It takes 42 seconds  to pull the data from server (using pullWithQuery) which has 8 table with 1500 records.

I changed the paging size from 50 to 1000, application URL from https to http and  create index ON in portal. After these changes it takes 12 seconds in 3G Network.

Currently I am using Mobilink for data synchronization which takes only 4 seconds to pull the same data from server using https.

I   tried by changing  the pricing tier for both App service and Azure SQL DB, but there’s no difference in the performance. Can the performance be improved in any other way?

Is there any service for Mobilink in Azure?

Is there any other database service that can be used which is comparatively faster?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue with NSHttpUrlSession re-use in the iOS SDK.  You can read about the fix here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client/pull/88 - the fix is merged but has not been released yet.  Once it is in a release, your offline data sync will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have done below settings for optimize Azure DB Synchronisation.

1. Made data centers of azure app service and azure database are same (Southeast Asia).
2. Increase app service instances to 2.
3. change app url to http instead of https.
4. create INDEX ON in perfomence insight.
5. changed page size to 1000 from 50.
6. created new framework with NSHttpUrlSession re-use in the iOS SDK.(based on your feedback created new framework)

But still database synchronisation takes 14 seconds in 3G (for 1700 records and 7 tables).

Can performance be still optimised?